# What things can be done to not get errors at running sdkmanager and other utilities of Android SDK (a version for command line)?

Tags: android, linux, linux-mint, android-developer-api

I try to compile an application written on `Python 3.10.12` in `Linux Mint 21.2` for Android. According to instructions, for example, [this one](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/), `Android SDK` must be installed. There is a possibility to download a version for command line usage (`commandlinetools-linux-10406996_latest.zip`) from [this webpage](https://developer.android.com/studio). It is enough to unzip a zip of the application into a directory and if necessary then to add some pathes to the `PATH` variable. Here is a content of the directory `~/path/to/cmdline-tools/bin`:

```
apkanalyzer  avdmanager  lint  profgen  resourceshrinker  retrace  screenshot2  sdkmanager
```

So it's pretty good — the `sdkmanager` exists in. Next I try to run `./sdkmanager` "as is" and with a parameter `./sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"` as well as written in [the instruction](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/). As a result I get an error: this one with using the `openjdk version "1.8.0_392"` (both `java` and `javac` are the same version):

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:621)
```

And this one with using `java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64` (again both `java` and `javac` are the same version being 11 in this case):

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

However, a JAVA_HOME variable can be tried to set. Here is a content of the `/usr/lib/jvm`:

```
default-java  java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64  java-11-openjdk-amd64  java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

I've tried to set both `java-8-openjdk-amd64` and `java-11-openjdk-amd64` for the `JAVA_HOME` adding `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` string into `~/.bashrc` but it hasn't helped. The error has remained.

**Question:**
what things can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while trying to install Android Studio for Flutter. From my notes... I used a tutorial from Digital Ocean to fix my Java installation issue.
Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-22-04

You already installed Java, so jump to *Step 2 — Managing Java*,
follow the document. I hope it fixes your problem.